# Android Studio doesn't recognize NotificationCompat.Builder.setSilent(Boolean) although the function is in the documentation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

I want to use the function [setSilent(Boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setsilent)
instead of the deprecated function [setNotificationSilent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setnotificationsilent) when creating a NotificationCompat.Builder but when I type the function in Android studio it doesn't recognize it, and I can't build the app.
I have checked the NotificationCompat.Builder class and it really doesn't appear there.
My code:

```
var notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Schedule")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_calendar)
                .setContentTitle("Schedule")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Stop Schedule", stopPendingIntent)
notificationBuilder.setSilent(true)
```

As a note, the setSilent() function is not in the builder's creation because it is toggled through an if statement. I have checked, and it doesn't recognize it in both places. That's also why using setSilent() will be so much better for me, because I want the notification to sometimes come with sound and sometimes not, and you can't disable the setNotificationSilent() function. That means that if I can only use that function I will need to rebuild the builder or keep to separate instances of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out what I did wrong.
My androidx-core library was outdated, and as such, it didn't recognize the setSilent(boolean) command, which is pretty new.

[androix-core version changes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core), I am pretty sure the method was added in the 1.5.0-alpha-02 version.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure NotificationBuilderCompat doesn't have the `setSilent` method because it was moved to the `priority` attribute. Use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` in `setPriority` to make the notification silent (i.e, no notificatino sound)

Comment: IMPORTANCE_LOW only exists from Android N (7.0), is there a way to do it so that's it's toggleable and more backward compatible?
Besides, there's still the fact that it's written in the documentation. I still haven't figured out if I am doing something wrong or if it's a mistake

Comment: Use the one in `NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_LOW`

Comment: Still has sound

Comment: What device are you testing it on? If you are using channels, you will have to set the importance of the channel as well

Comment: I test this on Android 11.
I know about channel importance, the importance of my channel is default because sometimes the notifications need to be with sound, so I can't just set it to low.

Comment: I can see it but it's deprecated `.setNotificationSilent` instead of `.setSilent`